# React-Redux-Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Class extends value # is not a constructor or null**

Error shows up when tried Inheriting a Parent Class which is binded with react-redux "connect" ->

**Redux**

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
      .....
});

const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
    return {
        paymentOver:()=>dispatch(paymentClose()),
    }
}
 
export {
    mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps
}
```

**Parent Class**

```
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps } from "../../State Management/MappingStates";
    
    Class MainContainer extends Component{
    
       componentDidMount(){
          this.props.paymentOver(); //redux action
        }
    }
   export default connect( mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps )( MainContainer )
```

**Sub Class**

```
import MainContainer from './MainContainer';
        
Class Sub extends MainContainer{  //Error showing at this line- Class extends value #<Object> is not a 
                                              //constructor or null
     render(){
            
        return ......
            
      }
}
export default Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, connected components are function components, so you cannot extends them.
Either way, even if it were a class component, it would be a new Component that just rendered your original class component. So neither way, you could extend this.

In general: in React, you should never extend components - even class components, but use other patterns like higher order components or composition.

Also, the whole ecosystem is shifting to function components for two years now. Unless you have a very good reason to (like maintaining a *very* legacy code base), you probably should not write class components any more.

That is also the [recommendation of the redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api): use hooks (`useSelector` and  `useDispatch`) and function components over `connect` and class components.

If you are just learning react & redux, you are probably following very outdated sources. For Redux, pleasee look at the official tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index